# Insert an Image into a video file in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to dynamically insert a picture into a video file for an iPhone app. What I was trying to do was a `chromakey`, and replace a color in the video with the image I wanted. Does anyone know a tutorial or framework for IOS that I can use, or should I proceed?

Comment: As a starting point I'd refer you here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9450056/862215 Then presumably you'd find the top-leftmost green patch and then superimpose the image on to it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you have a look at this [AVRender](http://www.modejong.com/AVAnimator/examples.html#AVRender) example, it does an offline rendering that will combine 2 videos into 1 on the iOS device and capture the results in a file. It is not exactly what you want to do, but it is very close and provides a framework that can be used. Getting into chroma replacement or OpenGL is going to be a big waste of time, it would be a lot better to just start off with videos that are already setup with an alpha channel so that processing on the device is less complex.